# do i need to reinstall all my softwares after upgrading ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

i was stopped by my sister from **upgrading Ubuntu**, for the reason she explained was that i would have to **reinstall all the softwares** that I've installed in last 6 months.
but i think if that's the case, the upgrade itself includes all softwares that i have installed.
so please tell me what's the truth?

> please note that i just can't afford mentally to reinstall all apps due to slow INTERNET speed.because it may take 3 to 4 days of constant downloading.
>   if you are an Indian living in an suburban city,you can understand my situation.

i think the question itself explains everything.still I'll explain everything in detail.i want to upgrade my current Ubuntu 12.10 OS to 13.10(now please don't ask what is 13.10). this option is available from **"about this computer"** and many other places.the upgrade is of about 700mb to 800 MB.

BTW, i don't know why i think it's a rule here to put some question on questions asked here,however detailed or/and simple it may be.at least that's what i feel after looking at many questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottom line is that you will upgrade, some things will break, some things will need additional drivers. The video driver alone for me was 124 Meg alone, I'm sure on a slow connection that can take a few hours.

Don't upgrade, its not worth it UNLESS you have problems and hope it will fix them with an upgrade. But if your computer is working. Stay away, its just not worth it.

Comment: that's something i needed.though i'm fond of using latest software,i could just keep away from it.but how about those regular upgrades which pop-up daily(or as per your settings) from software updater?

Comment: @adityapati l upgraded, and nothing new or great, in fact I dumped Ubuntu in favor of Mint Mate, which is based on Ubuntu because their Interface is more suited to a Desktop. The Ubuntu is trying to be a Tablet interface and you will agree, a desktop is not a tablet, which windows 8.1 is trying to be and they will fail. As too updates...I disable that, I upgrade critical kernel bugs but stay on same version otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean of upgrade?

If you mean the upgrade from Software Updater, no, it keeps all of your softwares and packages installed. However there’s a high risk of data loss, and also you need to download more than 700-800 MB which may be impossible for you.

According to the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes):

> Renewing the Installation without formatting the partitions (in contrast to upgrading), will also keep the personal data and configurations under /home but will renew all system settings under /etc as well as the default set of installed packages.

But if you mean a fresh installation with formatting the drive, yes, you should install all apps again. However you can keep your settings and personal data under `/home` if you have it on a separated partition.

More information on how to upgrade: [Raring Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RaringUpgrades)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to upgrade, then use

do-release-upgrade from terminal
or
update from update manager
or
from an iso image (offline n safer option...in case u drop internet connection in between)

u will not have to reinstall any software

if you fresh install overwriting the previous version,
then you have to reinstall all the software